# How to efficiently merge two dataframes in R, into a single one, recalculating the value for each new cell (preferrably using dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a MySQL table which contains data about some analyses I am doing. It looks like this:[mySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks2m2.png)

Here is also an example dataset corresponding to this table:

```
species  chrom  pos   strand  ratio   coverage  context  

X        Y      64    +       0.25    12        TACGT  

X        Y      65    -       0.5     20        ACGTT

X        Y      107   +       0.8     10        CCCGT  

X        Y      108   -       0.4     30        CCGTG
```

As you can see, I currently have a table with 7 fields. What i want to do is to merge all the cells for the "plus" strand with cells of the following "-" strand. I would then end up with a new table that contains 6 fields (all but the strand field) and half the rows of the old table. However, I need to recalculate the content of each cell in my new table based on the info of the old table that contains strand info.

So, the fields "species" and "chrom" contain identical information for each of the cells to be merged. I just need to keep one of the two. For the field pos I can keep only the info from the "+" strand. Same for the field "context". However for the fields "coverage" and "ratio" I need to perform calculations. The "coverage" field will contain cells that will be the sum of the "+" and "-" coverage cells. The "ratio" field will be calculated using the following function:

new_ratio=("ratio+" * "coverage+" + "ratio-" * "coverage-") / "coverage+"
+ "coverage-"

So this will be a function of the old ratios and coverages.

The new table should look like this:

```
species  chrom  pos  ratio       coverage  context  

X        Y      64   0.40625     32        TACGT  

X        Y      107  0.5         40        CCCGT
```

I have successfully written a script that can create a new table exactly the way I want it, but it takes FOREVER (I am doing this in R)!

What I am doing is that I split the table in two dataframes, the "plus" dataframe and the "minus" dataframe. Then I recreate the new table row by row by performing the calculations I described above.

This code is really inefficient as it takes too long to recreate the new table. I have tens of millions of entries in my original table (:

Is there a way to do this more efficiently, maybe by combining at once the "plus" and "minus" dataframes i created, and not having to do this row by row?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Pls provide data no pictures!

Comment: Thank you vaettchen! Are the data ok?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you Sotos! I reformatted the data! I think they look good now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# read in data
dat <- structure(list(species = c("X", "X", "X", "X"), chrom = c("Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y"), pos = c(64L, 65L, 107L, 108L), strand = c("+", 
"-", "+", "-"), ratio = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4), coverage = c(12L, 
20L, 10L, 30L), context = c("TACGT", "ACGTT", "CCCGT", "CCGTG"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

You can split the data into two according to the strand condition, and merge the two data frames together by species and chrom

```
dat[dat$strand == '+',] -> plus_strand
dat[dat$strand == '-',] -> minus_strand
merge(plus_strand, minus_strand, by=c('species','chrom')) -> newdat
# filter out lines where the difference between pos = 1    
newdat[newdat$pos.x - newdat$pos.y == -1,] -> newdat
```

The combined data looks as follows:

```
> newdat
  species chrom pos.x strand.x ratio.x coverage.x context.x pos.y strand.y ratio.y coverage.y context.y
1       X     Y    64        +    0.25         12     TACGT    65        -     0.5         20     ACGTT
4       X     Y   107        +    0.80         10     CCCGT   108        -     0.4         30     CCGTG
```

I do not how to back out the numbers you lay out above but this would seem to return the correct number of rows.

Comment: Hello Otto and thanx for your reply! Sorry i changed my example data again! I tried to make them even simpler looking! I will try your solution!

Comment: Hello again Otto. What you provided does not do what described! I end up with a dataframe that still has 4 rows. During the merging, I would like to merge the "plus" and "minus" dataframes by the "species" and "chrom" fields, and adding the corresponding columns pos.x , pos.y, ratio.x, ratio.y, coverage.x, coverage.y, context.x, context.y with two rows in total for the example I attached! Practically I would combine rows with the same row number into a single row for the plus and minus dataframes!

Comment: Your species and chrom fields are the same between your four lines.When merging the plus minus strands by species and chrom, how do you know that the first and second line need to be merged together, and the third and the fourth line need to be merged together? Is that dependent on the pos field somehow?

Comment: Hello again Otto, yes it is. The minus pos is always larger than the corresponding plus pos by 1. The pairs to be merged in the example are 64 merged with 65 and 107 with 108. I can just merge the dataframes by rownames and then use mutate to format each column into what I want. I am currently stuck on using mutate to create the ratio column! If I get to solve this I will post the solution, otherwise any additional help on this would be great!

Comment: The values for ratio for your test data can be calculated as follows: `newdat$new_ratio <- (newdat$ratio.x * newdat$coverage.x + 
newdat$ratio.y * newdat$coverage.y) / 
(newdat$coverage.x + newdat$coverage.y)`